# Google Sheets scatter plot stretches to fit my screen, how do I stop that?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I'm (unfortunately) stuck on my phone without access to a laptop most day, so when I'm messing around in Google Sheets, my scatter plots end up awfully stretched/squashed:

[image: two ellipses drawn using a scatter plot. The x-axis is stretched and the y-axis is squashed so the grid lines are not square]

As you can see the grid lines are not square.

I've edited that screenshot to demonstrate what I'm sort of after:

[image: the same scatter plot as above but image edited to make the gridlines square]

I can open the sheet in a browser from my phone (this doesn't fix the squashing/stretching) so I have access to the additional chart editing options there.

How can I fix the two axes to be a more 1:1 ratio?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, if you create a chart and move it to its own worksheet then you have no control over the overall shape of the chart as it is completely dictated by the w:h ratio of the window Sheets is running in (or in the case of a phone, the w:h ratio of the full screen). In order to control a chart's dimensions you need to make it within a normal worksheet. There is a 'Resize Charts' add-on which allows you to specify the exact dimensions in pixels, otherwise it's a case of using the mouse to drag the corners and eyeballing the result.

Comment: Ahhh, damn. Any idea how to move the chart into a work book?

Comment: Go to the worksheet the chart is in, then select 'Copy sheet' at the top of the screen, then change worksheet, click on any cell and then Ctrl+V to paste another instance of the chart at that location.